# .bat file running an excel macro in the background (or .vbs solution)

Tags: excel, batch-file, vbscript

I have the following issue:
- Task: There is a prepared excel that should be opened, and on opening a macro is executed.
- This task should be executed each day at a given time (like at 10:00), execution should happen in the background (so that the user is not disturbed at all).

Problem:
1) If I try to do it with a .vbs file (in task scheduler), then the execution happens in the background, however, some features are lost (there is an excel add-in that establishes connection with a company application, from which it should retrieve some data -> the connection is not set up, no data is received). I guess it lack privileges or something like that.
VBS bode is:

```
Dim objExcel
Set objExcel=CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.Run "'C:\SomePath.xlsm'!Module1.Controller"
```

2) If I try with a .bat file, it works (the connection is ok, data is received), however it flashes and is not running in the background. Simple code:

```
Start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Excel.exe" "C:\SomePath.xlsm"
```

Does someone have experience with this kind of issues?
I'm open to any other solution. :)

Thank you!

Comment: I believe you can set that specific Excel file up to `Workbook_Open()` to be `.visible = false`, so allow the connection, when using the .bat file.  That is one i've done in the past, thoguh you have to Enable Content on the first use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run it in the background like this in batch (The main part is the VBScript code):

```
<!--
@Echo Off
Cscript //Nologo "%~f0?.wsf" //job:VBS
Exit /B
-->
<package>
  <job id="VBS">
    <script language="vbscript">
       Dim WshShell : Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
       WshShell.Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Excel.exe 'C:\SomePath.xlsm'""", 0, True
    </script>
  </job>
</package>
```